# Online math editor and evaluation engine

Tags: javascript, math, web-applications, editor, evaluation

I'm trying to make a website that would help my students to evaluate their math knowledge.

The subject involves simple algebra like `5a-(2a+(2b-3a))= ?` and simple fractions.

I have two problems:

1. Students have to be able to input math easily. They have no experience with code like TeX. I can't expect them to input stuf like \frac{a}{b}.
   Which easy to use math editor library would you recommend?
2. How can i evaluate their answers. How can i evaluate input like `5a+2ab = 2ab+5a`. I already tried something out but student said afterwards that they entered `5 a` of `5*a` instead of `5a` and the system said it was wrong...

Are there any (javascript) library's that could help me accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: Fun! I would love to do this from scratch.

Comment: I would expect that if you removed all whitespace, then tried your solution, that it should work appropriately. But, then again, I don't know what other problems you may face.

Answer (score 2):

WolframAlpha has an [API](http://products.wolframalpha.com/api/). It can handle such requests fairly easily: [Demo](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5a%2B2ab%3D2ab%2B5%2aa)

It has a very comprehensive parsing engine that'll understand most correctly formatted mathematical expressions. Although I must admit that it might be a bit overkill...